# How to optimize broadcast join in spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am a new developper at Spark Scala and I want to improve my code by using a broadcast join.

As I understand, a broadcast join can optimise the code if we have a large DataFrame with a small one. It's exactly the case for me. I have a first DF (tab1 in my example) that contains more 3 billions data that I have to join with a second one with only 900 data.

Here is my sql request :

```
SELECT tab1.id1, regexp_extract(tab2.emp_name, ".*?(\\d+)\\)$", 1) AS city,
topo_2g3g.emp_id AS emp_id, tab1.emp_type

FROM table1 tab1

INNER JOIN table2 tab2
ON (tab1.emp_type = tab2.emp_type AND tab1.start = tab2.code)
```

And here is my attempt to use a broadcast join :

```
val tab1 = df1.filter(""" id > 100 """).as("table1")
val tab2 = df2.filter(""" id > 100 """).as("table2")

val result = tab1.join(
    broadcast(tab2)
, col("tab1.emp_type") === col("tab2.emp_type") && col("tab1.start") === col("tab2.code")
, "inner")
```

The problem is that this way is not optimized at all. I mean it contains ALL the columns for the two table, while I don't need all those columns. I just need 3 of them and the last one (with a regex on it), which is not optimal at all. It's like, we generate a very big table first and then we reduce it to a small table. While in SQL, we got directly the small table.

So, after this step :

- I have to use withColumn to generate the new column (with the regex)
- Apply a filter method to select the 3 colmuns that I. While i got them IMMEDIATELY in sql (with no filter I mean).

Can you help me please to optimize my code and my request ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you select the columns you want before doing the join

```
df1.select("col1", "col2").filter(""" id > 100 """).as("table1")
```

Comment: You didn't understand me well I guess. I am talking about selecting columns AFTER the join not at the initial dataframes...

Comment: ah ok. you applied the regex with sql functions over the dataset joined ?